# Why can't I always kill a docker process with Ctrl-C?

Tags: docker

I have a script which I want to optionally run within a container. I have observed that if I run an intermediate script it can be killed with `Ctrl-C`, however if I do not then it can't.
Here is an example:
`test1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" = true ]; then
  while true; do echo "args: $@"; sleep 1; done
else
  docker run --rm -it $(docker build -f basic-Dockerfile -q .) /test2.sh $@
fi
```

`test2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/test1.sh true $@
```

`basic-Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY test1.sh test2.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

Running `./test1.sh true foo bar` will happily print out `true foo bar`, and running `./test1.sh foo bar` will do the same in a container. Sending `Ctrl-C` will kill the process and delete the container as expected.
However if I try to remove the need for an extra file by changing `/test2.sh $@` to `/test1.sh true $@`:
`test1.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1}" = true ]; then
  while true; do echo "args: $@"; sleep 1; done
else
  docker run --rm -it $(docker build -f basic-Dockerfile -q .) /test1.sh true $@
fi
```

then the process can no longer be terminated with `Ctrl-C`, and instead must be stopped with `docker kill`.

Why is this happening?

Docker version 18.06.1-ce running on Windows 10 in WSL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a common *misunderstanding* in docker but it's for a good reason.

When a process run as PID 1 in Linux it behaves a little different. Specifically, it ignores signals as SIGTERM (which you send when hitting Ctrl-C), unless the script is coded to do so. This doesn't occur when PID > 1.

And that's why your second scenario works (The PID 1 is script2.sh, which delegates the signal in script1.sh, which stops because it is not PID1) but not the first one (script1.sh is PID 1 and thus it doesn't stop with SIGTERM).

To solve that, you can trap the signal in script1.sh and exit:

```
exit_func() {
        echo "SIGTERM detected"            
        exit 1
}
trap exit_func SIGTERM SIGINT
```

Or tell `docker run` to init the container with a different process as PID 1. Specifically, if you add `--init` to docker run with no more arguments, it uses a default program, [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini), prepared to handle these situations:

```
docker run --rm -it --init $(docker build -f basic-Dockerfile -q .) /test1.sh true $@
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also you can also use `exec` to replace the current shell with a new one which can be stopped with ctrl-c
For example start.sh script which starts nginx server and runs uwsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

service nginx start
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

should changed to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

service nginx start
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

After theese changes ctrl c will stop the container