# How to kill a port running concurrently ? Crtl + C on a terminal running npm concurrent "command1" && "command2" not working

Tags: npm, concurrency, port, kill-process

I have an React webapp on Webpack and have

> dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "npm run start" "npm run
> server""

in the package.json.
Running dev and then attempting to stop one the terminal says this:
`[1] Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`. Typing Y or pressing Crtl + C does nothing. I have to kill the ports each time (killing one port still kills the other).

I've tried the suggestion here as well: [Node JS ctrl + C doesn't stop server (after starting server with "npm start")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788982/node-js-ctrl-c-doesnt-stop-server-after-starting-server-with-npm-start)